# Conditional Formatting Last Line Pasted

Tags: excel, vba

I use copy and paste to pass data from sheet 2 to sheet 3 by adding the data in the last row but I would like that when the cell is written, this becomes orange with black border, I tried to use the `pastespecial` but it doesn't work for me, like do I have to give the command?

```vb
Sheets(3).Range("H" & (Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Range("H" & (Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Interior.Color = vbRed
Application.CutCopyMode = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
' it is assumed that the desired range has already been copied
With Sheets(3).Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    With Intersect(.EntireRow, .Parent.UsedRange)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 44   ' orange; or you can use .Interior.Color = 52479 instead
        .Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only works in part, when I run it, I color the entire row orange from column A to H, I would like to give orange even only to H or to the row from column B to H that contains the data

Comment: Use `.Parent.Columns("B:H")` instead `.Parent.UsedRange` in the code